# How to get the Windows OS release using powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell

I can view my windows os type using the following command

```
PS C:\> (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).caption

Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise
```

Is there a way to get only the OS release like `2008 R2` value using powershell?
Thanks!

Comment: What OS releases? Just windows server?

Comment: hi, yes in the windows server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try this:
 `(Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).caption.split()[4..5]`

Comment: Ah. that's cool. I've tried it in my server and tweaked few things. I got this final code to get the 2008 R2 -> (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).caption.split()[3..4] -join ' ' <-. But I wonder if it applies to other versions as well?

Comment: On my Windows 10 computer, the output of the command is: "Microsoft Windows 10 Pro". The word "server" is missing here, so you'd get bad output (you would need to change the indexes). Also, good that you added the -join specifier. My solution prints the words as one per line.